Can celibacy vows be annulled?
If a man vowed to be celibate can this vow be annulled?
Does the vow need to be annulled since it's a vow that prevents a mitzvah?

@DoubleAA in light of the Shach on YD 239:8 -- many think the vow is void ab initio, but the Shulchan Aruch considers it still valid; regardless it sounds like annulling it is the right move -- I suggest we reopen. This particular case is a bit more complex than the general "swore against a mitzvah." https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.239.8?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he

But in the end, yes it could and should be annulled.

The Shulchan Aruch's case was something much more, well, reasonable: a man who's never had kids married a woman, but they don't have any children. She has cancer, the doctors tell her she won't make it, and she demands that he swear never to remarry. If we can annul that case, we could certainly annul a vow of celibacy, which is completely contrary to halachic values.

Welcome to MiYodeya Dd7255 and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!
